# Extreme Beginner Question Access : Boolean -> True, only if ID is in another table

Tags: sql, ms-access, boolean

I would like to know how to automatically update a boolean field in a table whenever an instance of the `ID` is found in the placement table, the situation is as follows:

I have 2 Tables:

**Pupil Table**

- Pupil ID
- Placement Status (Boolean)

**Placement Table**

- Pupil ID

I want `Placement Status` to be true only when the ID of the pupil is found in the Placement table.

Please know that I'm very unfamiliar with every single term in the program, so a step-by-step solution will only do the trick.

Please if you do know, let me know with a lot of details as this is very essential to a project due in 2 days.

Thank you, and have a good day everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the `Placement Status` field using a simple update query such as:

```
update Pupil inner join Placement on Pupil.[Pupil ID] = Placement.[Pupil ID] 
set Pupil.[Placement Status] = True
```

Here, the `inner join` performs the implicit selection, and so no further selection criteria is required.